# CAST to DECIMAL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, casting, decimal

I am trying to cast to Decimal in MySQL like this:

```
CAST((COUNT(*) * 1.5) AS DECIMAL(2))
```

I'm trying to convert the number of rows in a table (times 1.5) to a floating point number with two digits after the point.

SQL code:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(Guardian.title, ' ', 
               Guardian.forename, ' ', 
               Guardian.surname) AS 'Guardian Name', 
               COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Activities', 
               (COUNT(*) * 1.5) AS 'Cost'
 FROM Schedule
 INNER JOIN Child ON Schedule.child_id = Child.id
 INNER JOIN Guardian ON Child.guardian = Guardian.id
 GROUP BY Guardian
 ORDER BY Guardian.surname, Guardian.forename ASC
```

It produces an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'CAST((COUNT(*) * 1.5) AS DECIMAL(12,2))' at line 1.
```

Another try, this cast also doesn't work:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(Guardian.title, ' ', 
               Guardian.forename, ' ', 
               Guardian.surname) AS 'Guardian Name', 
               COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Activities', 
               CAST((COUNT(*) * 1.5) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS 'Cost'
 FROM Schedule
 INNER JOIN Child ON Schedule.child_id = Child.id
 INNER JOIN Guardian ON Child.guardian = Guardian.id
 GROUP BY Guardian
 ORDER BY Guardian.surname, Guardian.forename ASC
```

How do I use mysql to cast from integer to decimal?

Comment: What kind of trouble?  Do you have a specific error message or result that shows the problem?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAST((COUNT(*) * 1.5) AS DECIMAL(12,2))' at line 1.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation and can't see why my code isn't working :S

Comment: Show us the whole code, not just a line. This [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23759/1) works fine.

Comment: `GROUP BY Guardian` ??? `Guardian` is a table, right? SHouldn't it be `GROUP BY Guardian.id` ?

Comment: Yes, probably - I'm new to this :P

Comment: This is a really old question, my apologies, but it looks like the cause for the error was never pointed out, so I just wanted to say that `CONCAT(...something... AS ...something..., ...more stuff here...)` is what's causing the syntax error. Compare `SELECT CONCAT('foo', 'bar', CAST(8 / 5 AS DECIMAL(12,2)));` and `SELECT CONCAT('foo' AS foo, 'bar' AS bar, CAST(8 / 5 AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS cost);`.

Answer (score 41):

From MySQL docs: [Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value) - DECIMAL, NUMERIC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html):

> In standard SQL, the syntax `DECIMAL(M)` is equivalent to `DECIMAL(M,0)`

So, you are converting to a number with 2 integer digits and 0 decimal digits. Try this instead:

```
CAST((COUNT(*) * 1.5) AS DECIMAL(12,2))
```

Comment: Thanks, although I've tried that already and just got the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECIMAL(12,2)) AS 'Cost'

Comment: @Ben: Don't use single quotes there: `AS 'Cost'`. Use: `AS Cost`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the error when I remove the quotes.

Answer (score 38):

### MySQL casts to Decimal:

**Cast bare integer to decimal:**

```
select cast(9 as decimal(4,2));       //prints 9.00
```

**Cast Integers 8/5 to decimal:**

```
select cast(8/5 as decimal(11,4));    //prints 1.6000
```

**Cast string to decimal:**

```
select cast(".885" as decimal(11,3));   //prints 0.885
```

**Cast two int variables into a decimal**

```
mysql> select 5 into @myvar1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 8 into @myvar2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @myvar1/@myvar2;   //prints 0.6250
```

**Cast decimal back to string:**

```
select cast(1.552 as char(10));   //shows "1.552"
```

Answer (score 12):

`DECIMAL` has two parts: `Precision` and `Scale`. So part of your query will look like this:

```
CAST((COUNT(*) * 1.5) AS DECIMAL(8,2))
```

`Precision` represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values. 
`Scale`  represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

Answer (score 3):

I'm lazy:

```
0 + colname
```

Furthermore, this works for fixed with any number of decimal places, float, etc.

See also `ROUND()` and `FORMAT()`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, I think for your purpose, is to use the round() function:

```
select round((10 * 1.5),2) // prints 15.00
```

You can try it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_round):