# trying to convert avg to a decimal, syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to turn my avg value in to a decimal, but am getting a syntax error:

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INT, avg(item_price)) as total_price, count(basket_item) a' at
>   line 4 in

my sql:

```
SELECT 
      item_id, 
      item_name, 
      CONVERT(INT, avg(item_price)) as total_price, 
      count(basket_item) as quantity, 
      item_price 
FROM basket b, items i
WHERE b.basket_user = ? 
AND i.item_id = b.basket_item  
AND i.item_quantity > 0
```

I have tried cast too but am getting the same error, I am using xampp php 7 version

Comment: try using `CAST(avg(item_price) as unsigned)`

Comment: @vkp `AVG()` will already return an integer.

Comment: use this CAST(AVG(item_price) AS decimal(11,2))

Comment: @BilasSarker You too, it doesn't make sense to convert an integer to an integer.

Comment: @sagi not like that. It should be decimal, check it.

Comment: It doesn't matter, `AVG()` only works with numeric values, and return a numeric value. I suspect he meant to convert the `value` it self, not the `AVG(value)` @BilasSarker

Comment: Have look on the link may be you can get your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830509/cast-to-decimal-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

avg is returning a DECIMAL. The code below should fix the problem.

[More information on casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

[`SELECT CAST(2.234 AS UNSIGNED) FROM DUAL;`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/65356)

```
SELECT 
      item_id, 
      item_name, 
      CAST(avg(item_price) AS UNSIGNED) as total_price, 
      count(basket_item) as quantity, 
      item_price 
FROM basket b, items i
WHERE b.basket_user = ? 
AND i.item_id = b.basket_item  
AND i.item_quantity > 0
```