# MySQL ORDER chars numerically

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, integer, varchar

I want to order this column which is a varchar value in mysql

```
13.25 
10
8.99
18.25
```

```
order by column asc
```

tankyou

Comment: Why would you store numbers like that in a VARCHAR datatype?

Comment: Research [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) as in `ORDER BY CAST(column, ToASensibleDataType) ASC`

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830509/cast-to-decimal-in-mysql

Comment: most simply, just do `order by 0+column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Order By CAST(colName AS DECIMAL(10,2)) ASC`