# Is there a way to specify the result type from math equation SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I was wondering if I could specify the return type of the result in a SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT 100 - 10 AS result
```

I would like for it to be decimal so with complex operations:

```
SELECT 9023.43 - 8012.21 AS result DECIMAL(10,4)
```

Is it possible to do this with SQL?

Alternatively it can be parsed by PHP but I'd rather have it return as decimal(10,4) using sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830509/cast-to-decimal-in-mysql), you can cast a value as decimal. In your example, this would look like this:

```
SELECT CAST((9023.43 - 8012.21) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS result
```